# Creating lines connecting each possible pair of points in PostGIS

Tags: postgis, point, polyline-creation

I am working with a group of points I would like to create lines connecting each possible pair of points.

Example: If I have points A, B and C I would like to have lines connecting A-B, A-C and B-C.

How can I do this in PostGIS?

[image: example]

Comment: For R: https://r-spatial.github.io/sf/reference/st_nearest_points.html

Comment: Sorry to say ... but i feel that question has been asked a thousand times ...

Comment: @snaileater. It probably has, feel free to find one, and suggest closing as a duplicate of.

Comment: just wanted to promote "searching" a bit ...

Comment: @snaileater. Lol, promoting searching without searching, super ironic :-).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In PostGIS, this can be done quite easily with a Cartesian product or `CROSS JOIN` in SQL, ie, joining a table on itself and using the [2nd form of ST_MakeLine](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_MakeLine.html). So, assuming a table called points with an id and a geometry called `geom`, this would look like:

```sql
SELECT 
    a.id, 
    b.id,
    ST_MakeLine(a.geom, b.geom) 
  FROM points a, points b
 WHERE a.id < b.id;
```

The comma between points a and points b is just syntactic sugar for CROSS JOIN. Setting `a.id < b.id` means that you will get a line between point 1 and point 2, but not between point 2 and point 1 and also you won't get a line between each point and itself (which will be nonsense, anyway). So, if you want the lines going  in both directions, change the `WHERE` clause so you just exclude cases where the points are the same, so you have:

```sql
SELECT 
     a.id,
     b.id,
     ST_MakeLine(a.geom, b.geom) 
 FROM points a CROSS JOIN points b
WHERE a.id != b.id;
```

In terms of runtime, if you have a.id < b.id, then in big O notation, this is n^2/2, whereas `a.id != b.id` is n^2, i.e., twice as much work/time.

Comment: Thanks, but Running: SELECT a.id, 
       b.id.
       ST_MakeLine(a.geom, b.geom) 
FROM riverscale.points a, riverscale.points b
WHERE a.id < b.id;


Returns: cross-database references are not implemented: b.id.st_makeline
LINE 1: SELECT a.id,         b.id.        ST_MakeLine(a.geom, b.geom...
                             ^ . What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Is riverscale a DB name or a schema name? If the former, you have your answer.

Comment: It's a schema name.

Comment: oh, my bad, there is a period not a comma after b.id. Fixed.

Comment: Thanks, it is working. One more thing: I tried to create a table with the result with "CREATE TABLE riverscale.lines AS
SELECT 
    a.id, 
    b.id,
    ST_MakeLine(a.geom, b.geom) 
  FROM riverscale.points a, riverscale.points b
 WHERE a.id < b.id;" but got an error saying "column "id" specified more than once"

Answer (score 5):

Let's assume we have 10 features in *"points"* layer respectively, see image below.

[image: input]

With the following query, it is possible to achieve the lines between all possible connection of points excluding themselves.

```sql
SELECT
    p1.id  || '-' || p2.id AS Name,
    MakeLine(p1.geometry, p2.geometry)
FROM
    points AS p1,
    points AS p2
WHERE
    p1.id <> p2.id
```

The output will look like

[image: output]

Comment: Fair enough, you posted while I was writing. I will leave mine anyway, as it is a pure Postgis solution and has further information about the WHERE clause.

Comment: By any means, thank you for posting! I will definitely check your answer because it includes explicit explanations from a PostGIS expert. Fair enough that our solutions partially overlap, however exact software was not determined bu the author in his question.

Comment: Thanks for the complement. Your answer is perfectly good and answers the question as first stated.

Comment: Greetings @Taras - I have a follow up question. Let's assume I am performing this operation above utilising polygon vertices and connecting them to each other. For concave polygons however I don't want to make connections "outside" of the polygon. I am using something like this `SELECT ST_MakeLine(a.geom, b.geom) AS geom FROM points a CROSS JOIN points b JOIN poly ON ST_Contains(poly.geom_s, ST_MakeLine(a.geom, b.geom)) WHERE a.id < b.id;` however it is utterly slow. Do you have any ideas how to speed this up?

Comment: Hello @TimothyDalton, i think it goes beyond the comment session. I suggest asking it either as a separate question or texting me in discourd. It will be kind if you can provide a piece of data for testing purposes. How big is your data? Are you working with PostGIS? Mind that a Virtual Layer is good but only to a certain extend.

Comment: Hi @Taras many thanks for your reply - I just created a new question here https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/407946/performant-possible-pairs-in-concave-polygon

Comment: Pörfekt :) Nice choice