# Finding shortest line ("arc") traversing a road

Tags: qgis, postgis, shortest-path

Is there any existing method (Qgis plugin, PostGIS etc.) to find the best (shortest) line (arc) to follow in order to traverse a road (represented as polygonal area)? If not, what algorithmic approach might be suitable here?
[image]

Comment: Possibly you could look at https://postgis.net/docs/ST_StraightSkeleton.html

Comment: @TimothyDalton Thanks, but I think both skeleton and medial are more or less "center line" which is not necessarily also the shortest line.

Comment: Maybe compute visibility connections could help you then. With these you could generate a topology and traverse over it yielding the shortest path. Have a look at this https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/407946/performant-possible-pairs-in-concave-polygon - you will have to make sure that the boundary of the polygon is sliced into edges, too.

Comment: @TimothyDalton Thanks, looks interesting

Comment: @TimothyDalton OK, you right-it will work. So it's not classical triangulation rather "all possible connections" to vertices constructing the road polygon boundary, and then MIN {simple shortest pathX4}: 2 possible starting points and 2 possible finish points.

Comment: Correct, that should do the trick @michael. I'd go with pgrouting. Should be up and running quite swiftly.